# Is Spring's SwitchUserFilter Thread Safe?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, impersonation

I've recently implemented `SwitchUserFilter` in my Spring (4.3.17) application.  While it initially looked like all was well we started running into 403 `Access Denied` errors, or suddenly getting redirected to our login page after exiting impersonation and then trying to re-impersonate the same or an alternate user.

I've spent a solid 3 days on this and have debugged deep into the depths of Spring at this point, focused primarily on the Filter Chain and authentication to try to understand what's happening.  What I've discovered is we're running into the following scenario:

1. Admin user impersonates a standard user
2. Admin user exits impersonation *before page fully loaded* (AJAX requests are pending)
3. Admin is correctly redirected to `SwitchUserFilter` exit `targetUrl`
   ...at this point, Spring security/auth/roles all look correct in the filter chain, session, and `SecurityContext.contextHolder`.  Then...
4. Spring begins processing an Ajax request originating from step 2, above.
5. Spring loads the authentication for the delayed request from the session and is *the impersonated user's auth*.
6. Spring processes the request, authenticates is since it sees the current session as the user's session, and the filter chain updates the `SecurityContext` with the *impersonated session*.

At this point the admin user is sitting on an admin-only page, but behind the scenes Spring has overwritten the `SecurityContext` auth with the user's.  Now if the admin attempts to reload the page they are redirect to admin login. If they attempt to impersonate they see a generic 403.

It appears to me that the only way step 5 occurs is if Spring has loaded the user authentication from the session, and then user exits impersonation and Spring restored admin's authentication to the session, and finally Spring completed processing of the (stale) user session auth and ultimately overwrites the admin session auth with the user's.

Apologies that this is so long-winded, it's been a frustrating few days and I'm not sure where to go from here.  It seems to me like this may be thread related, so wanted to ask and of course provide the necessary context.

Comment: You cannot prematurely exit something from the client. The server will still process the request (or finish the processing). So it might appear that the thing is getting cancelled in reality it isn't. And when that request finished processing the admin is indeed impersonating a user. Those credentials are stored in the session from that moment on. Yes it is thread safe and does exactly what it is supposed to do, but you simply cannot cancel a fired request.

Comment: @M.Deinum I do see the impersonation exit request complete first, and the admin's authentication restored to the SecurityContext holder and session. From that point forward it _is not possible_ to re-write the security context in that thread, to prevent the scenario I'm describing. However the pending AJAX request ultimately *does* overwrite the SecurityContext because it's not aware that it was already written in the other thread. Hence, it (by it I mean Spring) is not thread-safe wrt `HttpSession`. And for that reason, unfortunately, SwitchUserFilter is not reliable (though not its fault).

Comment: Ofcourse you Cannon re-write a securitycontext in a thread (if that would be possible that would be a quitte big security risk). Each request (not thread!) will overrede the context in the session, as that is how a request is handled. However the HttpSession (when used concurrently) isn’t thread-safe. You could make it thread-safe by using an object in the session for synchronization. However that would severly impact performance.

Comment: I appreciate your comments @M.Deinum -- in my research I stumbled across the `synchronizeOnSession` boolean of Spring MVC's `AbstractController`, I'm going to try that.  The article discusses the very situation I'm facing, overlapping AJAX requests and potential for inconsistent session.  Of course, I do understand how performance will be impacted, processing requests ~ serially.  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09238/index.html

Comment: That specific `boolean` won't help as it is on a controller. You have issues in a filter. You could apply the same approach in a servlet filter which would be in front of all other filters.

Comment: @M.Deinum Given that I can predictably reproduce the issue I'm seeing 100% of the time now I'm convinced this isn't a bug or a configuration issue but rather the nature of running a threaded web app that serves multiple client requests simultaneously. All of the reading I'm doing confirms this is entirely possible, and that `HttpSession` is not thread safe. I'm going to abandon `SwitchUserFilter` in favor of implementing impersonation so as to use unique sessions per impersonated user. Short of that, I'm not convinced there's a viable approach that won't result in crippling performance impact.